# delete call logs not working on HTC

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

i m trying to delete call logs of some selected numbers , code will be run successfully with required results on emulator and two other devices (Q-Mobile A500 & Sony Ericson X10i) that i have available for testing while client test on HTC one its not working

here is my code

```
    String num, queryString = null;

    number = number.replace(" ", "");
    number = number.replace("-", "");
    if (number.length() > 10) {
        num = number.substring(number.length() - 10, number.length());
        queryString = " LIKE '%" + num + "%'";
    } else {
        queryString = "=" + number;
    }

    // String queryString = "NUMBER=" + number;

    Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

    context.getContentResolver().delete(allCalls,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + queryString, null);

     context.getContentResolver().delete(
     android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
     android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + queryString, null);
```

i m trying to delete with both queries results are same but its cant work on HTC one

Comment: Do you see some results, when querying the url? with and without the filter?

Comment: @flx without filter i did not test while with filters i see that call logs are deleted

Comment: "its cant work on HTC one" -- this is not a useful description of your symptoms. Are you crashing? If so, post the stack trace. Also, why are you hardcoding the `Uri`, instead of using the `CONTENT_URI` from `CallLog` (since HTC may have moved it)? Also, since there is no requirement that the call log be backed by a SQL database, what makes you think that `LIKE` will be a reliable option?

Comment: @CommonsWare i used both hardcoded and CONTENT_URI both have same results while i checked it also backed by a sql database

Comment: call logs mainted in a db here /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db

Comment: So, you are saying that you broke into the offices of every Android device manufacturer and examined their changes to Android, to see how they handled the call log? After all, they are welcome to change the implementation of the call log just the same as they change the implementation of the home screen.

Comment: @CommonsWare can CONTENT_URI b different for different manufactures ?

Comment: It could be -- since it is a `Uri`, and not a primitive, it has to be constructed at runtime, not inlined into an app's bytecode. More importantly, the implementation of the provider itself can vary by manufacturer, and they may not all elect to support arbitrary SQL (since the `ContentProvider` API does not support arbitrary SQL like `LIKE`).

Comment: @CommonsWare problem solved htc one required permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />  while other mobiles works using tis permision   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete your call log by call id may be this will help.

```
int id = Activity_Name.this.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,"_ID = "+ calls_id_list.get(i),null);
        if (id == 1) {
            /*delete your call log*/

        }
```

may be through id you can resolve your issue.

Comment: For deleting all call logs you should follow
`Uri call_uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

int delete  = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"=?", new String[] {queryString});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the error:

On HTC One it is necessary to aquire the permission to wirte call logs:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

When compiling for a `targetSdkVersion` of 15 or lower this permission is granted automatically, but for higher `targetSdkVersion` this permission must be explicitly requested in the manifest.